# Publisher/Subscriber in JAX-RS - List not updating

Tags: java, jax-rs, publish-subscribe

So I'm trying to implement a publisher/subscriber pattern in JAX-RS however it seems that after the subscriber subscribes the publisher cannot find the subscription.

Server Code:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}/subscribe")
public void subscribe(@Suspended AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @PathParam("id") Long id) {
    if (responses.containsKey(id)) {
        responses.get(id).add(asyncResponse);
    } else {
        List<AsyncResponse> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add(asyncResponse);
        responses.put(id, newList);
    }
    System.out.println(responses.size());
}

@POST
@Path("{id}/publish")
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public void publish(String message, @PathParam("id") Long id) {
    System.out.println(responses.size());
    List<AsyncResponse> responseList = responses.get(id);
    if (responseList == null) {
        return;
    }
    for (AsyncResponse response : responseList) {
        response.resume(message);
    }
    responseList.clear();
}
```

Client Code:

```
public void subscribeToConcertNews(ConcertDTO concertDTO) {
    Response response = null;
    String url = CONCERT_URL + "/" + concertDTO.getId() + "/subscribe";

    ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url)
            .request()
            .async()
            .get(new InvocationCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(String s) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                    _client.target(CONCERT_URL + "/" + concertDTO.getId() + "/subscribe")
                            .request()
                            .async()
                            .get(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
                    throw new ServiceException("");
                }
            });


}

public void publishToConcertNews(ConcertDTO concertDTO, String message) {
    Response response = _client.target(CONCERT_URL + "/" + concertDTO.getId() + "/publish")
            .request()
            .post(Entity.entity("News!", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));

}
```

Testing Code:

```
ConcertDTO concertDTO = new ConcertDTO(1L, "123", new HashSet<>(), new HashMap<>(), new HashSet<>());
    _service.subscribeToConcertNews(concertDTO);
    _service.publishToConcertNews(concertDTO, "213123");
```

After the subscription, the size of the map is 1, however news is attempted to be published it reads that the size of the map to hold the responses is 0. So the AsyncResponse stored in the map is disappearing. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the whole server resource code. Is the resource class a singleton? If not, a new one will be created for each request. If you are going to make the resource class stateful, then it needs to be a singleton. You can do that by annotating the class with `@Singleton`

Comment: This seems like it would be the issue. I'll try resolve it and get back to you.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Thank you very much! I created a new singleton to store the responses and now it works!